# add js/css file to admin product grid using xml

Tags: magento

i am trying to add some js and css files on admin product grid using xml, but i am not able to add the files,i tried an alternative, check below

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('category_filter/lightbox.js');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('category_filter/cat_filter.js');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

But instead of using this code i want to add the files using xml can any one suggest me how to add those files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in some of layout xml files inside app/design/adminhtml/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout …
Reference:[inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-popup-dialog/)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js_css</type>
                <name>category_filter/lightbox.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js_css</type>
                <name>category_filter/cat_filter.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
</layout>
```

Comment: i am trying to add to this action <adminhtml_catalog_product_index>

Comment: did it work or not? If you want it to be applied in admin/product/grid then you need to remove action '<adminhtml_yourcontroller_youraction>' opening and closing both and then remove cache.

Comment: if i am not worng you meant this <adminhtml_catalog_product> which dint worked